# search text in pdf in iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am trying to do search functionality in iPhone. I pass the page number and the string to be searched.. but it is not getting the proper output. 
in contentStream I get nothing. I got this code by googling. I don't know what will be there in contentStream object.

```
-(BOOL)page:(CGPDFPageRef)inPage containsString:(NSString *)inSearchString {
[self setCurrentData:[NSMutableString string]];
CGPDFContentStreamRef contentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(inPage);
CGPDFScannerRef scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(contentStream, table, self);
bool ret = CGPDFScannerScan(scanner);
CGPDFScannerRelease(scanner);
CGPDFContentStreamRelease(contentStream);
return ([[currentData uppercaseString] 
         rangeOfString:[inSearchString uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
```

}

If there is any other solution then also it is fine.

Comment: you need to start asking better questions to get answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOU SHOULD IMPLEMENT THE COMPLETE CODE

http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42%22

check out the above link
a complete code to do so.

[image: profile for Fasttracks at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question and its answers for more information: [PDF search on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097044/pdf-search-on-the-iphone/)