# PDF search on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf

After two days trying to read annotations from a PDF using Quartz, I've managed to do it and [posted my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz).

Now I'd like to do the same for another frequently asked question: searching PDF documents with Quartz. Same situation as before, this question has been asked many times with almost no practical answers. So I need some pointers first, as I still haven't implemented this myself.

**What I tried:**

I tried using `CGPDFScannerScan` handling the `TJ` and `Tj` operators - returns the right text on some PDF, whereas on other documents it returns mostly random letters. **Maybe it's related to text encoding?**
Someone [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686924/which-are-the-pdf-operators-needed-to-do-a-search-feature-in-a-pdf-in-iphone-sdk/2717063#2717063) that text blocks (marked by BT/ET operators) should be handled instead, but I still haven't managed to do so. Anyone managed to extract text from any PDF?

After that, searching should be easy by storing all the text in a `NSMutableString` and using `rangeOfString` (if there's a better way please let me know).

But then how to **highlight the result**? I know there are a few operators to find the glyph sizes, so I could calculate the resulting rect based on those values, but I've been reading the spec for hours... it's a bloated mess and I'm going insane. Anyone with a practical explanation?

## Update

User Naveen Thunga found [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten), "a framework for extracting data from PDFs in iOS". I just tried the demo and it seems to work as advertised. I will test it with more PDFs and will post the results soon. As a side note, the code seems very good to me -- if you are interested in how this stuff works it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Found this collection of operators might be useful: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3627745/Getting-Text-Position-Parsing-Pdf-Quartz-2D

Comment: Hey Brainfeeder,You found any solution pertaining to highlighting the search result?

Comment: @Sarah: Nope, still nothing, I started focusing on other stuff after a few days...

Comment: okay..no problem.I surfed a lot,but not getting any way yet. Thanks any ways.I found your code quite helpful in some ways! :)

Comment: can you please replay for the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering-in-iphone

Comment: @pt2ph8 have you ever figured it out? If then your help can save lots of pepole.

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't worked on it anymore. As I said, if I'll ever come up with a solution I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a simple problem to implement, but it is straightforward.

For any given page you need to scan the page using the CGPDF scanner API.  You need to register callbacks for PDF operators that affect text in the page - not just TJ/Tj, but also those that set font, affect the text drawing matrix, etc.  You need to build a state machine that updates with each encountered tag+parameters.  You need to examine text accounting for the current font's encoding.  When you find text that you want to highlight, you'll need to examine the current text drawing matrix you've been updating to determine the drawing coordinates.  Read the PDF specification (version 1.7 is downloadable from Adobe) to understand which operators you need to pay attention to.

Font encoding is perhaps the most difficult part since there are a handful of ways encoding can be specified, and some of them are proprietary to the font.  Mostly you can cheat and fall back on a subset of ANSI encoding - but this WILL break on certain PDFs having strange fonts.

Essentially you are processing the page as if you were to render it.

Answer (score 3):

I created [utility class](https://github.com/Jageen/PDFSearch) in objective-c using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

Which will allow display as well as search PDF file.

Utility class allow search using `Highlight all search result` and 'case sensitive' options.

have look PDF search in action **[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KnvB_2930aVVViLWo5ZlpfcmM/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1):

So now in iOS 11 we have [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) with which searching text is a breeze

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: fileUrl)!
     let allText = pdfDocument.string /// Gets all text in pdf separated by /n

     let s: PDFSelection = pdfDocument.findString("Hello", withOptions: [])
     let sWithFormatting = s!.first!.attributedString
}
```