# How to search for non-ASCII characters ( cyrillic) in PDF using QuartzPDF?

Tags: ios, pdf, sdk, full-text-search, quartz-2d

I've stumbled upon a searching cyrillic (as well as any other non-ASCII) characters in PDF using PDDScanner. The code I am using is similar to mentioned to SO code from Randon ideas blog. The problem is that for cyrilic PDFs the output of scanner is a complete garbage, which can't be decoded to anything meaningful. English characters in cyrillic PDFs are searched just perfectly. So, the problem is that when it comes to cyrillic it is encoded and we can't get how to decode it properly.

What do we miss here?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed any light on the subject.

Comment: Can you post code, and also the link to said "Randon ideas blog"? Off the cuff it sounds like a character encoding issue, but PDF itself is thorny.

Comment: http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184  the code is straightforward cut-n-paste

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pushing that string through a different encoding? When I look at `NSString.h`, I see something suspiciously labelled "cyrillic" which also has "Adobe" on the same line :) (i.e., try `NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding`)

```
enum {
    NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
    NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
    NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
    NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
    NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
    NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
    NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
    NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,          /* kCFStringEncodingDOSJapanese */
    NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
    NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
    NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,    /* Cyrillic; same as AdobeStandardCyrillic */
    NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,    /* WinLatin1 */
    NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,    /* Greek */
    NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,    /* Turkish */
    NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,    /* WinLatin2 */
    NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,        /* ISO 2022 Japanese encoding for e-mail */
    NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,

    NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */

    NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,       /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

    NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,                   
    NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
};
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help. I tried to convert NSSTring using an encoding above but it is not working...

Comment: NSData *data=[currentData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *ddd = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];      the problem is that when I try to decode the whole stream returned by a scanner it returns null. other encodings again gave me a complete garbage again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to get deeper into the [Apple spec and headers on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html) - add NSLog lines (and post them here) for what the scanner finds for the normal PDF and the cyrillic ones. There are lots of possibilities (perhaps a different encoding, i.e. you need to translate the string you have to a different one using the encoding). I'm sure there is a way to list all the operators in the table, to see if there are extra ones in your cyrillic pdf. Also, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097044/pdf-search-on-the-iphone) as a vastly similar problem you're trying to solve - it points to a [library that is more tuned to scanning](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/blob/master/PDFKitten/CMap.m) too.

Comment: I added NSlog and got the following (an excerpt) ˜ ˜˚˚ ˛˚˚-˜˝-˙˝www.mediayug.ru˜˚˛˝˙ˆ ˇ˘ ˆ ˙ˆ  ˛˝˛ˆ: ˆˇ˘   ˘!                
    
 ˘     ˘,   
 ˘    ˘ 
      ˘ˇ˘      iPad ˜ ˚˛˝˙ˆˇ˘˙     ˚  ˘ˇ ˝  ˙˝ ˚˛˝˘    ˇ Android
2012-04-09 14:24:32.238 PublishLike[8939:16d03]  ı ¾ Ã ¶ Â ¾ À ¶   Å Æ Ä ¾ ½ ¸ Ä º Ç È ¸ ¶   ¾   Å Æ Ä º ¶ ¼   Ž €   Ã ¶   Æ Ä Ç Ç ¾ ¿ Ç À Ä Â   Æ Ñ Ã À »   Ç Ä Ç È ¶ ¸    Á Õ » È       ˇ     ¸   Ç Æ » º Ã » Â   ¸   È » Í » Ã ¾ »   Å Ä Ç Á » º Ã ¾ Ë

Comment: notice that english characters are bot encoded. but the rest of text looks cryptic.

Comment: Wish I could help more - who created/authored said pdf in the first place? Can you contact them? What PDF edit tools can you try/buy that might help you analyze the internal table codes?